# IOS writeToFile only write a part of file

Tags: ios

With the code below I succeed to write the pdf, but not all the file! I can see that the document is 3 pages, but only one page is writing. Does anyone know why?

(PresentationItem*)presentationItemFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict {

```
if (dict == nil) return nil;

CGPDFDocumentRef document = [self newPdfDocumentFromBase64DataString:[dict objectForKey:@"base64"]];

NSString *tempName = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

// Create the pdf context
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1);
CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
CFMutableDataRef mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL,0);

CGDataConsumerRef dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(mutableData);
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &pageRect, NULL);

if(CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) > 0){
    // Draw the page onto the new context
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Failed to create the document");
}

CGContextRelease(pdfContext);

// Write to disk

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.pdf", docDir,tempName];
[(__bridge NSData *)mutableData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];

PresentationItem *item = [[PresentationItem alloc] init];
[item setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
[item setDocument:document];
CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
CGDataConsumerRelease(dataConsumer);
CFRelease(mutableData);
return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS:**

check this code.. it will iterate for all pages & write each page to pdfContext. then save the file.

```
    if (dict == nil) return nil;

    NSString *tempName = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

    CGPDFDocumentRef document = [self newPdfDocumentFromBase64DataString:[dict objectForKey:@"base64"]];

    CGPDFPageRef page;

    CFURLRef pdfURLOutput = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:YOUR_OUTPUT_FULL_FILE_PATH];

    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(pdfURLOutput, NULL, NULL);;

    CGRect pageRect;

    for (int i=1; i<=CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document); i++)
    {
         page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i);

         pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);

         CGContextBeginPage(pdfContext, &pageRect);

         CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);

         CGContextEndPage(pdfContext);
    }

    CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
   // Write to disk

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


     NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.pdf", docDir,tempName];
     [(__bridge NSData *)mutableData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];

     PresentationItem *item = [[PresentationItem alloc] init];
     [item setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
     [item setDocument:document];
     CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
     CGDataConsumerRelease(dataConsumer);
     CFRelease(mutableData);
     return item;
```

Comment: I think you have right. Because if I a now change from 1 to 3, then I get the page number 3. But how can we write all pages. That's the question. Thank for Your help anyway.

Comment: @user2754113 see the new answer. It is exactly what you want.

Comment: I get error "Variable "pdfContext" is ininitialized when using here on line CGContextBeginPage(pdfContext, &pageRect);
By the way, I can't see where mutableData is declare?

Comment: After clean of the code I get another error on the same line: "Incompatible pointer type passing "CGRect" (aka 'struct CGRect*') to parameter of type "CFDictionaryRef (aka 'const struct _CFDictionary*)

Comment: @user2754113, i updated my answer with `pdfContext` init. Try it & tell me.

Comment: I just add two New lines inside the loop as following:

Comment: if(CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) > 0){
        // Draw the page onto the new context
        for(int i = 1; i<=CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document); i++){
            page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i);
            pageRect =CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
            CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
            CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);
            CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
        }
            }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Failed to create the document");
And everyting work fine. Thank you very much for Your help.